# Meaning of these two sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following conversation takes place between a seer and an individual almost 120 years ago in British India. The seer says -

> *If you can make your thoughts and words perfectly at one, if you can, I say, make yourself one in speech and action, money will pour in at
>   your feet of itself, like water.*

The language used here is dated. So when the seer says -

"*If you can make your thoughts and words perfectly at one*", does it mean that he is asking the listener to say exactly what he thinks?

He goes on to say - " *make yourself one in speech and action*", does this mean he wants the listener to practice what he preaches?

Comment: The incorrect English does not help, but I guess he is saying that your words, thoughts, and actions should always follow each other. I think your interpretations are correct.

Comment: @Stefan Thank You. It is possible that the English is incorrect, I'm not sure though, but it surely is dated. Maybe that's why it looks like it is incorrect.

Comment: The English is grammatically sound (though one can quibble about the first comma). The sentence recommends making thought, speech and action consistent. In other words, the person is to have integrity.

Comment: The phrase I found strange is the "make ... at one". I have now found that is an idiom, meaning "in agreement" - I just haven't heard that before

Comment: I believe that the seer was trying to be rather more subtle in what he was asking.  It's not just say what you think, but think about what you're saying.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin : I did modify my first comment in my second comment

Comment: Ah… sorry… missed that.

Comment: Your question belongs on a philosophy forum but since you’re here *if you can, I say* makes it perfectly clear *make your thoughts and words perfectly at one* means *make yourself one in speech and action* which in modern English is more like *walk your talk*. Though it seems to, that doesn’t at all mean *say exactly what you think*. That would be simply *speak your mind (truly)*. Broadly, *make yourself one in speech and action* is *be true to yourself* and yes, *practice what you preach* starts to get close.